# How to optimize a function existing as a embedded function block in simulink, part of MATLab, using fmincon?

Tags: optimization, simulink

`function y = objfun(x)
     sim('modelprototype.slx');
     y = Y(1);
 end`

It is in simulink embedded func block.

Before that I ask for help, I will explain what I did and what I want;

- I had a function as a script in matlab. Having entered the parameters to fmincon to optimize my fuction, It worked correctly. And iterated 9 times and lastly found the minimum value of my function;
- But the problem is occured when I decided to write the function in a embedded function existing in simulink model. Like I did above I entered all parameters for fmincon it only iterates 3 times and the values are same. I could not find the minimum value.
- Please help me to find a solution to optimize the function in simulink model like that same function written as ascript file in matlab.
- I want to write the function indicated in that link in simulink embedded function block and optimize it;

You can find information from the link below;
-https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html

You can reach Code and File
-https://github.com/saibermehmet/MATLAB.git

I again indicate that I want to optimize the obj function when it is a embedded function block in simulink instead of a ordinary function m-file.

Comment: You are unlikely to get any assistance unless you post some example code, and probably a model, that can be used to replicate your problem.

Comment: I added related code files via github. If you find out a way please let me know...

Comment: I have solved the problem :)